# Why application shows low memory warning during heap shot analysis?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, instruments

I am developing one application in which recurring transactions are inserted in database.while i am doing heap shot analysis it shows low memory warning while inserting data.its inserting 1200 records approximately.The code for insertion is as below.

```
-(void)generateReccuringEntry:(int)tranId withAllDate:(BOOL)isAll
{

    NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
     NSArray *arr = [[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_repeatd"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    int day;
      if ([self getDayWithDayMonth:[arr objectAtIndex:1]] == 0) {
        day = [self getDay:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    else{
        day = 1;
    }

    NSDate *startDate = [_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_date"];
     NSString *strEndDate = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_enddate"]];
   NSDate *endDate = nil;
    strEndDate = [strEndDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
  if (![strEndDate stringIsEmpty]) {
        endDate = [_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_enddate"];       
    }
    else {
        //if end date not selected
        endDate = [[startDate dateByAddingYear:1]lastOfYearDate];
    }

    //get start recurring day
    NSString *strDay = [[arr lastObject] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"()" withString:@""];
    //check start recuring day selected or not
    if ([strDay hasPrefix:@"("] && [strDay hasSuffix:@")"]) 
    {
        startDate = [self getStartDay:[arr lastObject] withStartingDate:startDate];
        if ([startDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedDescending || [startDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedSame) 
        {
            SafeRelease(arrDates);
            return;
        }
        if (isAll) 
        {

            NSError *error = nil;

            NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into recuring values (NULL,%i,%@,%@,'%@',%@,'%@','','%@','%@',%i,1,'%@',0)",tranId,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"cat_id"],[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"subcat_id"],_txtDesc.text,_txtAmount.text,sDate,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_repeatd"],eDate,_flagForever,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"categoryText"]];

            strQuery = [strQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
            [NSNumber requestWithSynchronousExcuteQuery:strQuery withReturnningError:&error];
            if (error) {
                [AppDelegate  showAlert:[error description] withTitle:@"Error!"];
            }
           }
        else{
            NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate date] getDateWithDeviceTimeZone];
            if ([startDate compare:currentDate]== NSOrderedDescending) 
            {



                 NSError *error = nil;

                NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into recuring values (NULL,%i,%@,%@,'%@',%@,'%@','','%@','%@',%i,1,'%@',0)",tranId,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"cat_id"],[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"subcat_id"],_txtDesc.text,_txtAmount.text,sDate,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_repeatd"],eDate,_flagForever,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"categoryText"]];

                strQuery = [strQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
                [NSNumber requestWithSynchronousExcuteQuery:strQuery withReturnningError:&error];
                if (error) {
                    [AppDelegate  showAlert:[error description] withTitle:@"Error!"];
                }

            }
        }
    }

    int index = 2;

    if (day == 1) {
        index = 1;
    }
    do {
       if ([[arr objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToString:@"Week"]) 
        {
            startDate = [startDate dateByAddingWeek:day];

        }
        else if([[arr objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToString:@"Month"])
        {
            startDate = [startDate dateByAddingMonth:day];

        }
        else 
        {
            startDate = [startDate dateByAddingDays:day];
        }
        if (isAll) 
        {


             NSError *error = nil;


            NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into recuring values (NULL,%i,%@,%@,'%@',%@,'%@','','%@','%@',%i,1,'%@',0)",tranId,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"cat_id"],[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"subcat_id"],_txtDesc.text,_txtAmount.text,sDate,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_repeatd"],eDate,_flagForever,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"categoryText"]];

            strQuery = [strQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
            [NSNumber requestWithSynchronousExcuteQuery:strQuery withReturnningError:&error];
            if (error) {
                [AppDelegate  showAlert:[error description] withTitle:@"Error!"];
            }


        }
        //add recuring for only for future dates
        else
        {
            NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate date] getDateWithDeviceTimeZone];
            if ([startDate compare:currentDate]== NSOrderedDescending) 
            {

                NSError *error = nil;

                NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into recuring values (NULL,%i,%@,%@,'%@',%@,'%@','','%@','%@',%i,1,'%@',0)",tranId,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"cat_id"],[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"subcat_id"],_txtDesc.text,_txtAmount.text,sDate,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"tran_repeatd"],eDate,_flagForever,[_dicSaveData valueForKey:@"categoryText"]];

                strQuery = [strQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
                [NSNumber requestWithSynchronousExcuteQuery:strQuery withReturnningError:&error];
                if (error) {
                    [AppDelegate  showAlert:[error description] withTitle:@"Error!"];
                }



            }
        }

    } while ([startDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedAscending );
      SafeRelease(arrDates);

}

can anyone tell that what is the problem with this code.so that its consuming so much memory?
```

Update:I have converted app to ARC.but it still shows memory warning.

Comment: In this code you have created too many autoreleased objects. You can create a temporary autorelease pool inside the while loop and drain it each time so that the memory occupied by autoreleased objects is available for use. But make sure you do retain those autoreleased objects which you will use later on in other part of application or else they will be released once the pool is drain and cause other issues. To know the exact memory footprint you should run application with Allocations instrument. It will give you an idea about how much memory is being used.

Comment: Read some coding guide lines first! And then ask about memory.

Comment: here no objects are autoreleased.saferelese is defined in prefix.pch as #define SafeRelease(var_name) if (var_name != nil) [var_name release]; var_name = nil;and heap shot analysis is done by running application with allocation in instrument.

Comment: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: There are tons of autoreleased objects here - every `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is an autoreleased object. All the dates I see are autoreleased above.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend you convert (if you can) to ARC. The compiler is far more capable of inserting the most efficient retains/releases for you. Would also completely remove any need for anything like SafeRelease.

Comment: i have added autorelease pool but still it shows memory warning.i can not convert project to ARC as i have used some libraries

Comment: Of course you can convert to ARC and still use non-ARC libraries. Just unclick the checkbox for classes that use those libraries (and ideally factor those out to a minimum of classes). I realize if it's widespread that may not be feasible though. But the main point is (I'm sorry) but it may be you don't have a full handle on release/autorelease. Your objects are already autoreleased - adding another one isn't going to help. To convert objects to non-autoreleased you'd have to change `[NSString stringWithFormat:..]` to `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:…]`, then add a release later on.

Comment: I have converted it to ARC.but it still shows memory warning.

Comment: Use Instruments and see if you have retain cycles (see earlier link I posted above from bbum). ARC certainly helps but is not a magic bullet - you have to measure first and understand where your consumption is before doing targeted improvements.